# Affine Cipher - Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: affine-cipher

Really simple question regarding the [Affine Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher).

Can someone tell me how $3^{-1}$ is supposed to result in 9 in the following explanation below?

[image]

Comment: 27 ≣ 1 (mod 26) and 3*9 = 27. Gotta pay attention to the modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the multiplicative inverse of an integer *a* (mod *n*) you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm. For two integers *a* and *b*, the Extendend Euclidean Algorithm not only calculate the greatest common divisor *d* but also two integers *x* and *y* that satisfy the following equation:

*ax* + *by* = *d* = gcd(*a,b*)     (where gcd is the greatest common divisor)

So **if *a* and *b* are relatively prime** (gcd(a,b)=1), *x* is the multiplicative inverse of *a* (mod y), and *y* is the multiplicative inverse of b (mod x).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) seems to provide a good explanation of the algorithm

Hope I was helpful!

Comment: The wikipedia article regarding "Modular multiplicative inverse" helped me to bring some light into the topic - the Euclidean algorithm will be covered later in the book. Thanks anway!

Comment: Good!! I thought you wanted to find the multiplicative inverse of an integer (mod n). Was I wrong?